# Grafana variable of a Prometheus __name__ filter metric and one graph for each

Tags: prometheus, grafana-variable

in prometheus I can list the metrics like this:

```
{__name__=~".+_count$", class=~"OracleCustomerDao$", application="access-registration-service"}
```

And in Grafana I have lots of the graphs where only the name changes:

```
sum(rate(db_query_issuer_settings_seconds_count{application="access-registration-service"}[5m])) by (dn)
```

But the number of metrics changes with every release and then I manually need to look up in Prometheus and add them manually as new graphs to the dashboard.

How can I add a Grafana variable of `__name__` (here: db_query_issuer_settings_seconds_count) and a for loop showing all the graphs that matches the Prometheus above?

Answer (score 3):

Create a variable at ***Settings*** > ***Variables***, using the following configuration:

```
Type        = Query
Data source = Prometheus
Query       = {__name__=~".+_count$", class=~"OracleCustomerDao$", application="access-registration-service"}
Regex       = /(.+){/
```

Comment: Test the Query in Prometheus first to see if it matches, thanks